# Relatórios em C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, relatório

Como eu faço relatórios para [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [asp.net-mvc-4](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4)?

Uso algo componente de terceiros ou faço uma página HTML mesmo?

O que vocês utilizam no dia-a-dia?

Pergunto, pois preciso imprimir relatórios que seguem um padrão do governo. Em [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) faço com os pés nas costas, mas em C# é a minha primeira necessidade.

Comment: Eu estou a usar o iTextSharp para gerar PDF's. Mas acredito que existam ferramentas melhores

Answer (score 2):

Aconselho utilizar o Crystal Reports. Segue alguns links:

- [Download Crystal Reports](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074)
- [Site SAP Crystal Reports para desenvolvedores](http://global.sap.com/brazil/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/developers/index.epx)

A implementação é simples e muito semelhante a qualquer software gerador de relatórios.
Segue um exemplo simples que retorna o relatório inserindo alguns parâmetros no relatório:

```
  public ActionResult relatorio_pdf()
    {
        connection.ConectarBanco();

        ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();

        rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Views/Relatorios/relatorio.rpt");//Indica o endereço do relatório
        rptH.Load();//Carrega o relatório
        rptH.OpenSubreport("relatorio.rpt");
        rptH.SetDatabaseLogon("usuario_banco","senha_banco");//Indica o usuário e senha do banco no qual o relatório está relacionado
        rptH.SetParameterValue("id_produto", 120);//Indica o parametro para o relatório
        Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);//Diz o tipo de stream, no pdf para Crystal Reports

        connection.FecharConexaoBanco();

        return File(stream, "application/pdf");
    }
```

Obs: Lembrando que esse exemplo é aplicável a relatórios que estejam ligados à um banco de dados em sua configuração. Esse processo não se torna necessário em relatórios com um DataSet relacionado, apenas utilize uma Controller onde carregue a página retornando uma Stream do seu relatório.

Answer (score 2):

Cara, não recomendaria usar nenhum componente.
Utiliza uma model bem feita que retorne seus campos corretamente.
Os componentes para exportar para pdf, Excel a maioria tem nativos.

Assim você ganha performance e não fica preso a nenhuma versão de componentes.

Comment: Porém como fazer a View ter o tamanho padrão de uma folha de A4, isto eu acho que será o meu maior problema, o resto de fazer na mão acho que seria muito mais fácil de fazer do que usando componentes.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que HTML não seja a saída para este caso - você vai se incomodar bastante para montar e depois fazer o ajuste fino no layout.

Caso essa sua necessidade no C# seja pontual (você irá continuar desenvolvendo em Delphi), você pode continuar processando o relatório em Delphi gerando como resultado um arquivo PDF, que depois pode ser [visualizado ao usuário final no browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086321/opening-a-pdf-in-browser-instead-of-downloading-it) *(Para alguns relatórios legados que temos, fazemos isso com ASP.NET + COBOL!)*.

No mais, existem várias ferramentas boas no mercado - vale (muito) a pena o investimento caso este tipo de projeto vire praxe. Listo aqui quais possuem interface de renderização do relatório na Web *(não necessariamente MVC)*:

- [SAP Crystal Reports](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ActiveReports/) *[(gratuito para desenvolvedores .NET!)](http://www.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-visual-studio/implement/licensing.html)*
- [Devexpress Reporting](https://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/Reporting/)
- [Telerik Reporting](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx)
- [ComponentOne ActiveReport](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ActiveReports/)

Comment: A necessidade é mesmo fazer online. Estou aos poucos tirando o projeto do Delphi para C# MVC